# Criteria API - OR comperator with unknown number of comparisons

Tags: java, jpa, filter, filtering, criteria

I'm trying to implement some kind of data filtering opportunity for my Java web Application.
In my case user should be able to filter clients who - for example where born after 2 December and have clientSate ACTIVE or INCATIVE.
In my case ACTIVE and INACTIVE are enum values.

Since user can choose 2 or 3 or even 5 different statuses I'm doing it like this:

```
for (EnumValue enumValue : constraint.getValues().getEnumValue()) {
    ClientState state = ClientState.valueOf(enumValue.getValue());
    predicate = builder.or(builder.equal(client.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), state));
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Here is my full function code:

```
    public List<Client> getClients(List<FilterConstraint> filters) {
    try {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<?> mainQuery = builder.createQuery(Client.class);
        Root<Client> client = mainQuery.from(Client.class);
        Predicate predicate = builder.conjunction();

        for (FilterConstraint constraint : filters) {
            switch (constraint.getOperator()) {
                case AFTER:
                    predicate = builder.and(builder.greaterThan(client.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), constraint.getValues().getStartDate()));
                    break;
                case BEFORE:
                    predicate = builder.and(builder.greaterThan(client.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), constraint.getValues().getStartDate()));
                    break;
                case BETWEEN:
                    if (constraint.getField().getType() == FieldDataType.DATE) {
                        predicate = builder.and(builder.between(client.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), constraint.getValues().getStartDate(), constraint.getValues().getEndDate()));
                    } else {
                        predicate = builder.and(builder.between(client.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), constraint.getValues().getMinValue(), constraint.getValues().getMaxValue()));
                    }
                    break;
                case EMPTY:
                    predicate = builder.and(builder.isEmpty(client.get(constraint.getField().getValue())));
                    break;
                case EQUALS:
                    if (constraint.getField().getType() == FieldDataType.ENUM) {
                        if (constraint.getValues().getEnumValue().size() > 1) {

                            for (EnumValue enumValue : constraint.getValues().getEnumValue()) {
                                ClientState state = ClientState.valueOf(enumValue.getValue());
                                predicate = builder.or(builder.equal(client.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), state));
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                        ClientState state = ClientState.valueOf(constraint.getValues().getEnumValue().get(0).getValue());
                        predicate = builder.or(builder.equal(client.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), state));
                        break;
                    }
                    predicate = builder.and(builder.equal(client.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), constraint.getValues().getValue()));
                    break;
                case LESS_THAN:
                case MORE_THAN:
                case NOT_EMPTY:
                case ON:
                case STARTS_WITH:
                case TODAY:
            }
        }

        CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
        cq.select(builder.count(cq.from(Client.class)));
        em.createQuery(cq);
        cq.where(predicate);
        Long count = em.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();

        mainQuery.where(predicate);
        //TODO Pagination Result should be returned
        TypedQuery<?> q = em.createQuery(mainQuery);
        List<Client> allClients = (List<Client>) q.getResultList();
        return allClients;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

}
```

I have searched a lot and wasn't able to fund the example where was no exact value for OR operator - actually I found comparing 2 values or 3 - not more.

Can someone tell me how can I fix my code to be able to support any number of values in OR expression ?

Answer (score 1):

[`CriteriaBuilder.or`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#or(javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate...)) accepts an array of predicates. So just create an array of "equals enum value" predicates and call `or` of that array once.

Alternatively, you may want to consider `in <enum values>` instead.

Comment: ArrayList<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
                                for (EnumValue enumValue : constraint.getValues().getEnumValue()) {
                                    ClientState state = ClientState.valueOf(enumValue.getValue()); predicates.add(builder.equal(client.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), state)); }   predicate = builder.or(predicates);   -- it tells me : not exepted input. what I'm doing wrong? can you give me code example?

Comment: @Irakli Look, this was good enough for a hint. I poitely decline writing your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

lexicore is right. You can give it an array like this:

```
 if (constraint.getValues().getEnumValue().size() > 1) {
      List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
       for (EnumValue enumValue : constraint.getValues().getEnumValue()) {
         ClientState state = ClientState.valueOf(enumValue.getValue());                                    predicates.add(builder.equal(client.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), state));
  }
 predicate = builder.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
     break;
  }
```

This code should work for you

Comment: In this case only Or expresion is evaluated and the other predicates are ignored. I need they all to be included.